# Consumir REST windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rest

Estou tentando consumir um REST JSON, estou desenvolvendo um módulo para um sistema legado em Windows Forms, não está dando certo, não retorna nada.

Segue o código:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://selador.homologacao.portalseloam.com.br/auth");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);


request.JsonSerializer.DateFormat = "POST";
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("username", "xxxxxx", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("password", "xxx@xxxx", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("client_id", "xxxxxxx", ParameterType.QueryString);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password", ParameterType.QueryString);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Os parâmetros `username`, `password`, `client_id` e `grant_type` são obrigatórios.

---

Criando um método separado e tentando pegar o resultado pela chamada "Call().Result".

Chega nessa linha ele trava o sistema

```
var request = await cliente.PostAsync("/auth", content);



static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    var response = Program.Call().Result;
}

static async Task<string> Call()
{
    var parametros = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parametros.Add("username", "004143");
    parametros.Add("password", "fpf@1212");
    parametros.Add("client_id", "selador");
    parametros.Add("grant_type", "password");

    using (var cliente = new HttpClient())
    {
        cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://selador.homologacao.portalseloam.com.br");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parametros);
        var request = await cliente.PostAsync("/auth", content);
        return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Outra dúvida

Como faço para gerar um objeto Json com o seguinte formato:

```
{
 "ato": {
  "codigo": "030011",
  "codigoTabelaCusta": "0320161001"
 },
 "natureza": {
  "tipo": 1
 },
  "partes": ["DEVEDOR", "APRESENTANTE, CREDOR"],
  "selo": {
  "convenio": false,
  "escrevente": "USUÁRIO DE SUPORTE PADRÃO",
  "protocolo": "12345",
  "valorTitulo": 511.00
 }
}
```

Já gerei passando como uma string e deu certo, gostaria de saber como gerar um objeto Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo usando o [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    var response = Program.Call().Result;
}

static async Task<string> Call()
{
    var parametros = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parametros.Add("username", "004143");
    parametros.Add("password", "fpf@1212");
    parametros.Add("client_id", "selador");
    parametros.Add("grant_type", "password");

    using (var cliente = new HttpClient())
    {
        cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://selador.homologacao.portalseloam.com.br");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parametros);
        var request = await cliente.PostAsync("/auth", content);
        return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Lembrando que esta é a forma recomendada de se fazer requisições Web a partir do `.Net 4.5`

Note que o link `https://selador.homologacao.portalseloam.com.br` não possui um certificado verificado, portanto não é considerado seguro, por isto irá acontecer uma exceção ao executar este código.

Porém é possível fazer um arranjo técnico para que certificado não seja validado, porém não aconselho que ignore esta verificação no ambiente de produção;

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

o código acima está retornando a seguinte string.:

```
{ 
   "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.e7UnBuT0ZXew9ZQDIpZURMor_TYAa2Ewhqu6VOrFzwYg0KHKRrMKPReJdjVPEdM-WR_UatG_sWa7BVLuiED02lHDl1pKzjN6F2zHJYC-85kgIkb4KMBKz9qfYkTOn50scQMWxV_4_0YONlu56ZBBiHzq1ZdJnrl4L-9MkELaDr1QoGwBRHYDlOBeQfMpsECGa-x4AaqqFRREAdzx-N-nxIkOHY8v_kBBu_EkvgP9Bflp_olHNvucMP-yLSkuQCGDDwDz6sd9Oe-ZNr2i_EEubVzibvQh4LvIyJffq8uGtlSHJqS0mExU0jLBa2m5xyMo9FSgTlbZ2mxCihfWLGO0-A",
   "expires_in":600,
   "refresh_expires_in":600,
   "refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.myAKI_WQBt-8dOcfCjh98J0KLqNq-s3qk87e0lyQaUeHRxcQpj3bUb6pvlXDn35NoNKdufxG5_MSby5eqKfoLIsRz1BTMluYkk5EVaaQ_TTZvpPMyG5f9Ab5BfG5fM1w3mtiZM3jh4EOh1WVixCNB3VO0zNpHpk-H6yxuqss3YmZk98OPhI7oV1RONsA2EIFbLX2hIbND2CVBZOi0G1f3skzhJpxaRg0hcvN0cifvtQ56D4y0DPc8IMbYoJLK3XYTCxhTeYtLwAw3rlrsDs9io9_ZIwQQMhrrFaw5HqwcH9-4jPUuQUQ6oaO50syjJ-SLITxgQkeanuNX7S433TKcw",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.KlU4e66Na1HLxik_aFQLoY_MMkatbFAnet6yzi2aSSRopQoJF14H9kv6mU-ziLabmPBasiHa-VEkwAwOO-SelhTDAAv6mguO0LMfy-HAuhKMDVcRpuoHsF0jwklEOUC2KeC6T2fdI7su8Sn5v5aRuj1bSxwOD9VluY21_zYGQ34E0CJKwudzLDkLM6CF-xoC5Y69TORdVPzztXyUgafQ_pExVnM--0TLB8jUL2YXQaOZk7oAB0tAiDo7rUqKyERpI4sjtV-GjutcC3vJWH-hHiIfJFxjik5HutuH245uQ5lp-N-dfUkVvp1A-bDTnB4LKgmCMzXze2B63H4se3xZZg",
   "not-before-policy":1447334813,
   "session-state":"bf3348ec-34d8-434b-8148-fd8c3cda47e0"
}
```

então antes de trabalhar sobre este objeto, aconselho que deserialize a mesma. para tal defina uma classe com a seguinte estrutura.

```
[DataContract]
public class DadosAcesso
{       
    [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "refresh_expires_in")]
    public int RefreshExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "refresh_token")]
    public int RefreshToken { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "id_token")]
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "not-before-policy")]
    public int NotBeforePolicy { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "session-state")]
    public Guid SessionState { get; set; }
}
```

Então use o [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
var response = Program.Call().Result;
var dadosAcesso = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DadosAcesso>(response);
```

**EDIT - Enviando um JSON**

A primeira coisa à se fazer é `serializar` o seu objeto, feito isto você terá uma `string` que contem um `json`.

Então você poderá instanciar um `StringContent` passando a string com o json e informando o mime-type `application/json`.

```
var objeto = new MyObjeto { MyProp1 = "For", MyProp2 = "Bar" };
var json = await Task.Run(() => {
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objeto);
});

using (var cliente = new HttpClient())
{
    cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://selador.homologacao.portalseloam.com.br");
    var content = new StringContent(json , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var request = await cliente.PostAsync("/auth", content);
    return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Toby, tentei executar o código que você me passou, mas está dando um erro nessa linha aqui:                                                                                                              var request = await client.PostAsync("/auth", content);                                      {"A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Não foi possível estabelecer relação de confiança para o canal seguro de SSL/TLS."}

Comment: @ThiagoMartins apos realizar algumas correções nos nomes das variáveis, tentei realizar o Request, porém o mesmo foi recursado pq o certificado usado no site é invalido, então precisei fazer uma gambiara para poder consumir este serviço.

Comment: @ThiagoMartins fiz uma edição com vários detalhes.

Comment: muito obrigado, exatamente o que eu precisava. Muito bem explicado, parabéns.

Comment: como faço para referenciar a biblioteca desse [DataContract]?

Comment: @ThiagoMartins, System.Runtime.Serialization

Comment: mesmo referenciando a biblioteca  System.Runtime.Serialization não consigo encontrar o [DataContract], fica como se não estivesse referenciado.

Comment: @ThiagoMartins. você precisa incluir a referencia no projeto e o using no arquivo.

Comment: deu certo, eu estava vacilando, estava esquecendo de referenciar a dll no projeto. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: como faço para preencher um body JSON utilizando o HTTPClient?

Comment: @TobyMosby, muito obrigado brother, deu certo.

Comment: @TobyMosby, acrescentei mais uma dúvida na minha pergunta, se puder me ajudar nessa...

Comment: @ThiagoMartins, caso tenha novas dúvidas, por favor crie novas perguntas, por exemplo, ao perguntar como enviar um JSON, você mudou o escopo da pergunta, isto não é interresante para StackOverflow, neste caso o ideal seria abrir uma nova pergunta com a nova dúvida.